# Laplace Theorem for determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Can someone explain to me the proof of Laplace theorem for determinant clearly and in a short way cause I'm on first year in college and proof I found on the internet are too hard to be understood.Any help would be appreciated.Thank you!

Comment: What is Laplace's theorem for determinants?

Comment: @littleO it's another name for cofactor expansion apparently!